# Recursively get parent nodes from specific node

Tags: arrays, swift, tree

I need to make a function that returns all parent nodes from a specific node in a tree structure.

This is an example of the structure:

```
struct Node
{
    var name: String
    var id: Int
    var parentId: Int?
    var children: [Node]

    init(name: String, id: Int, children: [Node], parentId: Int?)
    {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.children = children
        self.parentId = parentId
    }
}
```

This would be an array of Node.

```
Array(
    Node("A1", 1, [
        Node ("A11", 11, [
            Node("A111", 111, []),
            Node("A112", 112, [])
            ]
        )]),
    Node("A2", 2, [
        Node ("A21", 21, [
            Node("A211", 211, []),
            Node("A212", 212, [])
            ]
        )]),        
    )
)
```

If I select Note "112" I should get an array like this:

```
[Node("A1", 1, [...]), Node ("A11", 11, [...]]
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Here's a testable example:

```
let nodeA111 = Node(name: "A111", id: 111, children: [], parentId: 11)
let nodeA112 = Node(name: "A112", id: 112, children: [], parentId: 11)
let nodeA211 = Node(name: "A211", id: 211, children: [], parentId: 21)
let nodeA212 = Node(name: "A212", id: 212, children: [], parentId: 21)

let nodeA11 = Node(name: "A11", id: 11, children: [nodeA111, nodeA112], parentId: 1)
let nodeA21 = Node(name: "A21", id: 21, children: [nodeA211, nodeA212], parentId: 2)

let nodeA1 = Node(name: "A1", id: 1, children: [nodeA11], parentId: nil)
let nodeA2 = Node(name: "A2", id: 2, children: [nodeA21], parentId: nil)

let nodes: [Node] = [nodeA1, nodeA2]

// This is the function I want to do
func getParentNodes(forNode node: Node) -> [Node]
{
    return []
}
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: This is only possible if you maintain a registry (a dictionary) that maps node IDs to node instances. Otherwise, knowing a `parentId` is `11`, there's nothing you can do with it